# $this->image_lib->resize(); return false

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using the code to resize the image if the file size is greater than 1MB,am using this in the model function,but it returns false.Whats wrong here.

```
if($_FILES[$name]['size']/(1024)>1024){

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config2['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';  
    $config2['source_image'] = $upload_data["file_path"];  
    $config2['create_thumb'] = TRUE;  
    $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;  
    $config2['quality'] = '60%';  
    $config2['width'] = 200;  
    $config2['height'] = 200;  
    //$config2['new_image'] = $upload_data["file_name"];  

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2); 
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);

    var_dump($this->image_lib->resize());

}
```

Comment: write `if` in a more appropriate way:- `if( ( $_FILES[$name]['size'] / 1024 ) > 1024 ){`

Comment: Do we have to include ImageMagick libraries ?if so where to include it?

Comment: At the top of your php code after `<?php` using `include()` or `include_once()`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't load image_lib in if. Try to use code below

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

if($_FILES[$name]['size']/(1024)>1024){

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config2['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';  
    $config2['source_image'] = $upload_data["file_path"];  
    $config2['create_thumb'] = TRUE;  
    $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;  
    $config2['quality'] = '60%';  
    $config2['width'] = 200;  
    $config2['height'] = 200;  
    //$config2['new_image'] = $upload_data["file_name"];  

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);

    var_dump($this->image_lib->resize());

}
```